# App Crashing: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: android, exception, android-sqlite

I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong, Have I declared anything wrong,I am not able to identify the problem here.

```
MainActivity.java
public class New_Appointment extends AppCompatActivity {

    String username, password, user_type, spl, slt, hs, he, ss;
    Spinner specialization, slot;
     int hsi, hei, tmp;

    DatabaseHelper dbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_appointment);

        Bundle bb = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bb != null) {
            username = bb.getString("username");
            password = bb.getString("password");
            user_type = bb.getString("user_type");
        }
        specialization = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_specialization);
        slot = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_slot);

        List<String> s_slot = new ArrayList<>();
        s_slot.add("Morning (9-12)");
        s_slot.add("Afternoon (1-4)");
        s_slot.add("Evening (5-9)");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_slot = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s_slot);
        adapter_slot.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        slot.setAdapter(adapter_slot);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("username", username);
        b.putString("password", password);
        b.putString("user_type", user_type);

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.b_refresh:
                slt = slot.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int r1, r2;

                //SELECTING RANGE FOR SLOT
                if (slt.charAt(0) == 'M') {
                    r1 = 9;
                    r2 = 12;
                } else if (slt.charAt(0) == 'A') {
                    r1 = 13;
                    r2 = 16;
                } else {
                    r1 = 17;
                    r2 = 21;
                }

                dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                Cursor y = dbh.checkduplicates_in_user_credentials("", "", getResources().getString(R.string.all_doctor_slots));

                if (y!=null && y.moveToFirst()) {
                    List<String> s_specialization = new ArrayList<>();
                    Set<String> set_s = new HashSet<>();

                    // CHECK SLOT
                    if (y.getString(5).equals("Y")) {

                        hs = y.getString(3);
                        hsi = ((int) hs.charAt(0) - (int) '0') * 10;
 Pointing ERROR  --->   hsi += ((int) hs.charAt(1) - (int) '0');

                        he = y.getString(4);
                        hei = ((int) he.charAt(0) - (int) '0') * 10;
                        hei += ((int) he.charAt(1) - (int) '0');


                        if ((r1 <= hsi && r2 >= hsi) || (r1 <= hei && r2 >= hei)) {
                            ss = y.getString(2);

                            for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i++) {
                                if (ss.charAt(i) == '_') {
                                    if (i + 1 < ss.length()) {
                                        String ad = "";
                                        for (int j = i + 1; j < ss.length(); j++) {

                                            if (ss.charAt(j) == '_') {
                                                i = j - 1;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            ad += ss.charAt(j);
                                        }

                                        if (ad.length() != 0)
                                            set_s.add(ad);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!y.isLast()) {
                        y.moveToNext();
                        while (true) {
                            hs = y.getString(3);
                            hsi = ((int) hs.charAt(0) - (int) '0') * 10;
                            hsi += ((int) hs.charAt(1) - (int) '0');

                            he = y.getString(4);
                            hei = ((int) he.charAt(0) - (int) '0') * 10;
                            hei += ((int) he.charAt(1) - (int) '0');

                            if ((r1 <= hsi && r2 >= hsi) || (r1 <= hei && r2 >= hei)) {
                                ss = y.getString(2);

                                for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i++) {
                                    if (ss.charAt(i) == '_') {
                                        if (i + 1 < ss.length()) {
                                            String ad = "";
                                            for (int j = i + 1; j < ss.length(); j++) {

                                                if (ss.charAt(j) == '_') {
                                                    i = j - 1;
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                ad += ss.charAt(j);
                                            }

                                            if (ad.length() != 0)
                                                set_s.add(ad);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                            if (y.isLast())
                                break;
                            y.moveToNext();
                        }
                    }


                    Iterator iterator = set_s.iterator();

                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        s_specialization.add(String.valueOf(iterator.next()));
                    }

                    Message.message(New_Appointment.this, String.valueOf(s_specialization.size() + " specializations found"));


                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_spl = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s_specialization);
                    adapter_spl.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    specialization.setAdapter(adapter_spl);
                } else {
                    Message.message(New_Appointment.this, "Sorry no slots available");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.b_search :
                slt = slot.getSelectedItem().toString();
                spl = specialization.getSelectedItem().toString();
                b.putString("specialization", spl);
                b.putString("slot", slt);

                Intent i = new Intent(New_Appointment.this, Select_Doctor.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Native Method)
         at com.hospital.appointment_booking.InstaCure.Patient.New_Appointment.onClick(New_Appointment.java:96)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

As soon as I click on the schedule its crashing.I I am trying to access the available doctor slot from patient and as soon as I search, its throwing this error.Even when I made changes,Its showing the same error.

Comment: That means that `hs` is only one character long, which would mean that the value in column 3 of at least one position in your `Cursor` is only one character long. If that's not what you're expecting, there's not enough information for us to be able to tell you why, exactly. Also, I would suggest that you use more meaningful variable names, not only to help yourself keep track of things, but to make it easier for others to read your code when you need help.

Comment: thank you got your point,it works

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1` says it all.